# TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 2024-03-16 12:34:56.789000 of type <class 'datetime.datetime'>. For column literals, use 'lit',

Tags: pyspark

When I run this simple code I get the below error. I could not figure it out why ? And spent too much time. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, FloatType

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
date_time_d = [("2024-03-15 00:00:00.000", "2024-03-16 12:34:56.789"), 
        ("2024-03-01 00:00:00.000", "2024-03-18 01:23:45.678")]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(date_time_d, ["date_f", "dt_to"])
df1.show()

df2 = (df1.withColumn("from_date", to_timestamp(col("date_f"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
       .withColumn("to_date", to_timestamp(col("dt_to"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
)

f1 = udf(lambda f_dt, to_dt: (unix_timestamp(to_dt)- unix_timestamp(f_dt)), FloatType() )

df4 = df2.withColumn("diff", f1(col("from_date"),col("to_date")))
df4.printSchema()
df4.show()
```

Error :

TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 2024-03-16 12:34:56.789000 of type <class 'datetime.datetime'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.